# Naming memory mapped files

Tags: c++, memory-mapped-files

According to the documentation, after Local\ or Global\ any character is ok except for the backwards slash. I decided to name my mmf according to the file path of the physical file like this:

```
    std::string GetMapName(std::string FilePath) {
        std::string Ret("Local\\");
        char* pP = (char*)FilePath.c_str();
        for (int i = 0; i < Path.size(); i++) {
            if (pP[i] == '\\') pP[i] = '/';
        }
        Ret.append(FilePath);
        return Ret;
    }
```

So if the file is at C:\test\vht1.tst then it produces the string "Local\C:/test/vht1.tst"

I have no issues with this on my computer but this software is going to end up in a shared hosting environment and I couldn't really find much information on the convention of naming MMF's so.. Is this a good idea?

Comment: You're not allowed to modify the contents of the string returned by `.c_str()`.

Comment: well it works.. but I'm guessing its not guaranteed to do so, what would you suggest for character replacement then?

Comment: Use `FilePath[i]` instead of `pP[i]`.

Comment: I don't think your code will work on a Unix host. On Unix, `/` is a directory separator, but `\ ` is just an ordinary filename character.

Comment: well doh! didn't know string had a bracket operator.

Comment: So if the input is `Foo\Bar` on Unix, that doesn't imply that there's a `Foo` directory.

Comment: According to what documentation? What's a map name? Memory mapped files work differently on different operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons to name your MMF mapping (Memory Mapped File):

- An interface between readers & writers of the MMF
- An identifier to help you debugging

Unless you have a very large project, you are unlikely to have local name collisions.  You literally can name it anything you like.

Including the drive letter and path are probably not the best choice.  Keep it simple:

```
std::string GetMapName(std::string filePath)
{
  return "Local\\" + Path::GetFileName(filePath);
}
```

According to the docs[1], you should not use the "Session\" prefix.  It's reserved for system use.  And the "Global\" prefix requires SeCreateGlobalPrivilege.

[1] https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa382954%28v=vs.85%29.aspx